# What does a negative percentage difference tell me about my results?

Tags: data

If I am trying to determine the percentage difference between two values, and I get a negative value for the percentage difference between two results, generally speaking what does a negative value for the percentage difference tell me about how the two results compare.

Comment: Taking the absolute value is a part of the calculation, maybe you missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. Yesterday a liter of petrol was €6, today it is €4. We want to calculate the relative increase in percent. The absolute change is €4 - €6 = -€2. We divide the absolute change by the base value, so -€2/€6 = -0.3333 = -33.33%.

So we may say that the price increased by minus 33.33%. Of course nobody says such a thing, you will say instead the the price **decreased** by 33.33%.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematically

To calculate the **percentage difference**, you first calculate the **numeric difference**:

$$\text{Percentage difference}=\frac{b-a}{a}\qquad \left(\text{sometimes written:}\quad \frac{b-a}{a}\cdot 100 \%\quad\right)$$

If the difference $b-a$ is negative, then the percentage difference becomes negative. For example:

$$\text{Percentage difference}=\frac{7-5}{5}=\frac 25=0.4=40\,\%$$
$$\text{Percentage difference}=\frac{3-5}{5}=\frac {-2}5=-0.4=-40\,\%$$

So, all a negative value means is that $a$ was larger than $b$. If positive, then $b$ was larger than $a$.

### Physically

You are leaving your house but forgot your wallet. When you are $s_\text{start}=5\,\mathrm m$ away from the driveway, your brother runs out after you with. He catches up with you when you are $s_\text{end}$ metres away. Two cases:

$$\text{Percentage distance}=\frac{s_\text{end}-s_\text{start}}{s_\text{start}}=\frac{7\,\mathrm m-5\,\mathrm m}{5\,\mathrm m}=\frac {2\,\mathrm m}{5\,\mathrm m}=0.4=40\,\%$$

$$\text{Percentage distance}=\frac{s_\text{end}-s_\text{start}}{s_\text{start}}=\frac{3\,\mathrm m-5\,\mathrm m}{5\,\mathrm m}=\frac {-2\,\mathrm m}{5\,\mathrm m}=-0.4=-40\,\%$$

- In the first case, you are farther ahead when he catches you than you where when he started running after you. You managed to add 40 % extra metres while he was running.
- In the second case, you are *closer* when he catches you than you where when he started running. This naturally means that you must have heard him and turned around and walked towards him to greet him.

We have here implicitly worked with a coordinate direction. A coordinate axis which points away from the house. The *positive* direction has been implicitly chosen to point away from the house. So, farther from the house we have higher position values on this axis. A negative value of anything (speed, difference in position etc.) just means that we have moved *opposite* to whichever direction we chose to be positive.